# What time of day are Scheduled Reminder Event Emails sent?

Tags: civievent

The 'Scheduled Reminders' tab for events allows the user to set an exact date for a Scheduled Reminder Email to be sent, but there is no option to specify a particular time on that date.

What time of day are such emails sent by civi? Is it 12:00am on the day? Because this is the first time that it is true that the date matches? Or is there some other default time set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This varies but is configurable.

If you go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs** you'll see a job called *Send Scheduled Reminders*.  It will also say what time the job was last run.  It will run 24 hours from the last time it was run.

You can edit the job to force it to run next at a given time. It will then run 24 hours from when it was previously run.

A good improvement would be to allow specifying a time, which should be possible these days - CiviCRM stores a time internally to deal with timezone issues.  This would be especially helpful for users who have modified the scheduled job I mentioned above to run more frequently than daily.